# Test to count how many variables are in a environment (Postman)

Tags: java, variables, environment-variables, postman

I'd like to count how many environment variables I have in an Environment in POSTMAN.

In my Environment called, `UUID Test`, I have 10 variables that I have set:

```
UUID_1
UUID_2
UUID_3
..
UUID_10
```

I've tried a number of versions which I put into the Test field in the Request (see below)

V1:

```
let counter = parseInt(pm.environment.get("counter"))
console.log(counter)
```

V2: Using the Environment name in quotes.

```
let counter = parseInt(pm.environment.get("UUID Test"))
console.log(counter)
```

With both of these versions I am receiving a `Nan` in the console.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Would this work `Object.keys(pm.environment.toObject()).length`?

Comment: @DannyDainton it is not.  Nothing populates in the console, any console.log to perform?

Comment: `pm.environment.toObject()` should show all the variables in the active environment file, then it's a case of counting the length. https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-environment-variables-in-scripts

Comment: You're obviously going to need to wrap that in a `console.log()` statement to see the results in the console 

Comment: Thank you @DannyDainton - That worked!

Comment: Added an answer, if that's what you need, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(Object.keys(pm.environment.toObject()).length)
```

That should give you that length of the variables in the environment file.

Comment: Thanks, I also have another question I asked today if you got the time :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307634/loop-a-collection-of-requests-w-different-variables-until-variable-count-is-com